# @OneToOne Relationship Spring Data JPA/Hibernate Entity Relationship

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on adding a feature to an already developed spring boot web application. The primary entity that has child entities is a Record. It has a few columns/variables that I want to now be in its own, separate entity (CustomerOrder) and exist in a one-to-one relationship with the Record. To summarize:

Record {

- thing 1
- thing 2
- thing 3

}

is now becoming:

CustomerOrder {

- thing 1
- thing 2
- thing 3

}

Record {
CustomerOrder
}

I'm having some issues with what I've produced. Here is the CustomerOrder model's relevant relationship data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="customer_orders")
public class CustomerOrder {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ... other columns

    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="customerOrder", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Record record;


}
```

And then here is the Record model's relevant data:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="records")
public class Record extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    ... other columns

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_order_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
}
```

My issue exists when I try to POST a record, when a user tries creating one in the ui. Here is the POST method for a record:

```
    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveRecord(@RequestBody Record recordBody, BindingResult result) {
        if(!result.hasErrors()) {
            if(recordBody.getHardwareItems().isEmpty()) {
                record = recordsService.save(recordBody);
            } else {
                // Save the record first, recordId is required on hardwareItems
                // TODO: investigate Spring Hibernate/JPA rules - is there a way to save parent before children to avoid a null recordId
                CustomerOrder customerOrder = recordBody.getCustomerOrder();
                recordBody.setCustomerOrder(new CustomerOrder());
                customerOrder.setRecord(record);
                customerOrder = customerOrdersService.save(customerOrder);
                record = recordsService.save(recordBody);
            }
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getAllErrors(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        // Return the location of the created resource
        uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{recordId}").buildAndExpand(record.getId()).toUri();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(uri, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

The error I receive is the following:

```
2021-02-19 00:46:28.398  WARN 29990 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2021-02-19 00:46:28.398 ERROR 29990 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Field 'record_id' doesn't have a default value
```

This makes sense to me at least, since I'm trying to save the CustomerOrder object that depends on a Record object, which has yet to have been persisted. So, how do I go about changing up the order and/or creating and persisting a Record object so that I can then save the CustomerOrder object to it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your column `record_id` as `AI(AUTO_INCREMENT)` in your table definition.

```
ALTER TABLE records CHANGE record_id INT(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Your primary key is `record_id`, add `@Column(name = "record_id", nullable = false)`

```
@Entity
@Table(name="records")
public class Record extends Auditable<String> implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "record_id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    ... other columns

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_order_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private CustomerOrder customerOrder;
}
```

Comment: The record's id is already set with "strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY", which already automatically increments the value, correct? So what am I missing in terms of why AUTO_INCREMENT would be necessary?

Comment: @CDA the Programmer No, it will not automatically increment the value, you need to set AUTO_INCREMENT  in the table definition as well

Comment: unfortunately, this did not solve the issue as I am still getting the same error

Comment: @CDA the Programmer, Your primary key name is `record_id ` so change  `private Long record_id;` this in the entity

Comment: Sorry, I must not be understanding your direction here. I apologize for my inexperience here. But could you explicitly write out what to change and where? I tried exactly to change ```private Long id;``` with ```GenerationType.IDENTITY``` to ```GenerationType.AUTO``` in the Records table. This did nothing. I also did the same on the id for the CustomerOrders table.

Comment: @CDA the Programmer I have updated the answer, follow the step, and let us know the result.

Comment: Thank you for typing that out. Unfortunately, still getting the error that "'record_id' doesn't have a default value". If you take a look at the controller, do you think there may be an issue with that method?

Comment: record_id present in which table?

Comment: I added the entire error response to when I make an attempt to POST in the answer above.